# JPQL Adding Lists into HashMap, multiplying List records

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpql

Hello fellow programmers, I want to add in loop multiple lists into HashMap. I dont't know why when its getting to second iteration records are multiplied e.g. there is 10 records for February( monthId = 2) and after whole loop there is 40 of them injected. Below is code:

```
public HashMap<String,List<Transaction>> convertTransactionsPerMonth(int 
userId){
    for(int monthId = 1; monthId < 13; monthId++){
    ArrayList<Transaction> transactionsFromDatabase = new ArrayList<> 
    (entityManager
            .createQuery("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE 
    MONTH(t.transactionDate) LIKE :monthId AND t.user.id = :userId", 
    Transaction.class)
            .setParameter("monthId", monthId)
            .setParameter("userId", userId)
            .getResultList());
    transactionsPerMonth.put(Months.getById(monthId), 
    transactionsFromDatabase);
    }
    return transactionsPerMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two numbers in sql you use `=` and not `LIKE`

```
"SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE 
MONTH(t.transactionDate) = :monthId AND t.user.id = :userId"
```

also it looks like `transactionsPerMonth`is declared outside of the method and then returned, are  you sure it is empty when the method is called? Probably better to declare it as a local variable.

Comment: Thank for advice with comparing two numbers, that was usefull. transactionsPerMonth is empty at beginning, reason I've done that is because I want to use it also in another method that receive only its key in String. Here is declaration of this HashMap:                                                                                                   private HashMap<String, List<Transaction>> transactionsPerMonth = new HashMap<>();